Colocalizing closure of an abelian category and homotopy limits of double truncations
Let $A$ be a complete abelian category and $D(A)$ it unbounded derived category. Set $C = Coloc(A)$ be the colocalizing closure of $A$ in $D(A)$, that is the smallest triangulated subcategory of $D(A)$ containing $A$ and closed under small products.
What are the assumptions for $A$ that imply $C=D(A)$?
Clearly, $C$ contains all bounded (on both sides) complexes and closed under homotopy limits (more or less by definition). My idea was to take a complex and present it a homotopy limit of bounded complexes, by taking two-sided truncations. Let $X$ be a complex, set
$$
X_{(n, m)}=\ldots \to 0\to \operatorname{coker} d^{n-1} \to X^{n+1} \to \ldots \to X^m \to 0 \to \ldots
$$
for $n<m$. Then we have an inverse system $(X_{(-n, n+1)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. The inverse limit of this system is isomorphic (in the category of complexes) to $X$. To conclude that the homotopy limit is quasi-isomorphic to $X$ we can try to show that the following sequence of complexes is exact
$$
0 \to X \stackrel{\theta}{\to} \prod_{n \geq 0} (X_{(-n, n+1)}) \stackrel{1-\varphi}{\to} \prod_{n \geq 0} (X_{(-n, n+1)}) \to 0,
$$
where map $\varphi$ is determined by the compositions with product canonical projections $p_n \circ \varphi = X_{(-n, n+1)} \to X_{(-n+1, n)}$, similarly $p_n \circ \theta=X \to X_{(-n, n+1)}$ defines map $\theta$.
I'm stuck at verifying that the sequence is exact. Any suggestions or refences to similar arguments (with one sided truncations for homotopy limits or colimits) will be appreciated.

Do you want any extra condtions on the abelian category $A$? If $A$ does not have property $AB4^\ast$ (i.e., if products are not exact) then the product in the category of complexes is not in general a product in the derived category. I'm not even sure that the derived category of a complete abelian category necessarily has all small products.

Yes, I'm  happy with AB4*

I'll show that the sequence
$$
0 \to X \stackrel{\theta}{\to} \prod_{n \geq 0} (X_{(-n, n+1)})
\stackrel{1-\varphi}{\to} \prod_{n \geq 0} (X_{(-n, n+1)}) \to 0
$$
is a short exact sequence of complexes if we interpret the products as products
in the category of complexes, and so $X$ is in the colocalizing closure of $A$
if products in the derived category are the same as products of complexes (i.e.,
if $A$ is an $\text{AB}4^{\ast}$ abelian category).
For ease of notation, I'll assume that $A$ is a module category so that I can
describe maps in terms of elements, but everything can be interpreted in a
general abelian category. I'll say a bit more about this at the end.
First, to prove that we have a short exact sequence of complexes, it suffices to
prove that we have a short exact sequence of modules in each degree. In degree
$n$, the inverse system is of the form
$$\cdots= X^{n}= X^{n}= X^{n}\to\operatorname{coker}d^{n-1}\to0\to0\to\cdots$$
or
$$\cdots= X^{n}= X^{n}= X^{n}= X^{n}\to0\to0\to\cdots,$$
depending on whether $n<0$ or $n\geq0$.
For the second case it is enough to prove that, writing $M$ for $X^n$,
$$
0 \to M \stackrel{\theta}{\to} \prod_{n\geq0} M \stackrel{\phi}{\to} \prod_{n
\geq 0}M\to 0
$$
is a short exact sequence of modules, where
$$\theta(m)=(m,m,m,\dots)$$
and
$$\phi(m_{0},m_{1},m_{2},\dots)=(m_{0}-m_{1},m_{1}-m_{2},m_{2}-m_{3},\dots).$$
The first case is similar, except that then the purported short exact sequence
has a subsequence
$0\to0\to\operatorname{coker}d^{n-1}\xrightarrow{\sim}\operatorname{coker}d^{n-1}\to0$,
and taking the quotient by this sequence reduces to the second case.
Define maps
$$
M \stackrel{\beta}{\leftarrow} \prod_{n\geq0} M
\stackrel{\gamma}{\leftarrow} \prod_{n \geq 0}M
$$
by
$$\beta(m_{0},m_{1},m_{2},\dots)=m_{0}$$
and
$$\gamma(m_{0},m_{1},m_{2},\dots)=(0,-m_{0},-m_{0}-m_{1},-m_{0}-m_{1}-m_{2},\dots).$$
A straightforward calculation show that $\beta\theta$, $\phi\gamma$ and
$\theta\beta+\gamma\phi$ are all identity maps, so our purported short exact
sequence is in fact a (split) short exact sequence.
Note that all the maps used here make sense in any additive category. For
example, $\gamma$ is the map with $p_{0}\gamma=0$, $p_{1}\gamma=-p_{0}$,
$p_{2}\gamma=-p_{0}-p_{1}$, etc.
By the way, the fact that we get a split short exact sequence in each degree implies
that the short exact sequence of complexes induces a distinguished triangle in
the homotopy category $K(A)$, and so $K(A)$ is generated as a colocalizing
subcategory by $A$, regardless of whether $A$ is $\text{AB}4^{\ast}$.

Thanks! But why $\operatorname{coker} d$ is replaced by $\operatorname{im} d$?

@Alex Sorry, I meant coker. I'll correct that.
